# Gson illegal type variable reference

Tags: java, android, generics, gson, type-erasure

I have a class defined as:

```
public class Calls<T extends Object>
```

Inside this class there is a method `doRequest` that creates a `TypeToken` (from `com.google.json.reflect`) for a Gson request.

```
java.lang.reflect.Type type = new TypeToken<HandlerResponse<T>>(){{}}.getType();
```

where `HandlerResponse` is a simple model class that contains attributes like:

```
private Map detail;

private transient T data;

private transient int count = 0;

private String status;
```

The exception I get on Android Studio is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: PID: 32628
java.lang.AssertionError: illegal type variable reference
    at libcore.reflect.TypeVariableImpl.resolve(TypeVariableImpl.java:111)
    at libcore.reflect.TypeVariableImpl.getGenericDeclaration(TypeVariableImpl.java:125)
    at libcore.reflect.TypeVariableImpl.hashCode(TypeVariableImpl.java:47)
    at java.util.Arrays.hashCode(Arrays.java:4153)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$ParameterizedTypeImpl.hashCode($Gson$Types.java:479)
    at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.<init>(TypeToken.java:64)
    at com.company.server.Calls$4.<init>(Calls.java:244)
```

crashes at the instantiation of the TypeToken (I was thinking that probably is losing the T class 'cause of the type erasure of Java).

I create the instance of `Calls` as:

```
Calls<com.company.model.beans.Model> calls = new Calls<>(){};
```

Comment: This `new TypeToken<HandlerResponse<T>>(){{}}.getType();` won't do what you think. The corresponding `Type` will reflect the type variable `T`, not the type inferred.

Comment: When you instantiate a type token with a generic type parameter, it won't help you much, because `T` does not exist at runtime (except of class info). You have not to instantiate type token right there, but delegate it from somewhere (e.g. via a `Calls` constructor), thus instantiating the type token at the _call site_, e.g. `Type stringHandlerResponseType = new TypeToken<HandlerResponse<String>>(){}.getType()` and `new Calls(stringHandlerResponseType)`. Note that now you have a _real_ type. By the way, you have a typo: `{{}}` should be just `{}`.

Comment: You are correct @LyubomyrShaydariv the correct usage i with `{}` (as in this [example](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html)) and I did as you suggested, I moved the TypeToken object on the constructor and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, I modified the implementation as follows:

```
public class Calls<T> {

    public Calls(Type type, Class classTypeResponse) {

        this.type = type;
        this.classTypeResponse = classTypeResponse;
    }

    doRequest(...) { ... }

    ...
}
```

I have a `classTypeResponse` because I have a callback system that returns the right class type for the object for the request.

I call it in this way:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<HandlerResponse<com.company.model.beans.Model>>(){}.getType();

Calls<com.company.model.beans.Model> calls = new Calls<>(type, com.company.model.beans.Model.class);

calls.doRequest(...);
```

The `T` doesn't exists at runtime, Java reflection system couldn't infer the right type for the `TypeToken`. The solution is to create the `TypeToken` without generics and pass the object where you need it.

Comment: By the way, you can write down `<T extends Object>` merely as `<T>` because `T` always implies "extending by object".

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv yes, it's something that stayed there when I was trying to fix the problem.